# call php-cgi from c++ with REQUEST_METHOD="POST"

Tags: php, c++, shell

i am want to convert a shell script to c++. Please help me.

this is my shell script file. it worked well, but when i move to c++, it is not work correctly

`test.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
REQUEST_DATA="var_1=val_1&var_2=val_2"
export GATEWAY_INTERFACE="CGI/1.1"
export SERVER_PROTOCOL="HTTP/1.1"
export QUERY_STRING="test=querystring"
export REDIRECT_STATUS="200"
export SCRIPT_FILENAME="/test.php"
export REQUEST_METHOD="POST"
export CONTENT_LENGTH=${#REQUEST_DATA}
export CONTENT_TYPE="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8"
echo $REQUEST_DATA | /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

and `test.php` is

```
<?php
   print_r($_POST);
?>
```

when i run `sh test.sh`, i got response:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.13
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=f4ntbasno365p08tf94drl7026; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Array
(
    [var_1] => val_1
    [var_2] => val_2
)
```

When i am trying to convert this to c++

```
char **sysCline = NULL;
char **sysEnv = NULL;
std::string sData = "var_1=val_1&var_2=val_2";

std::vector<std::string> aArgs;
aArgs.push_back("/usr/bin/php-cgi");
aArgs.push_back("/test.php");
sysCline = new char*[aArgs.size() + 1];
for (i=0; i<aArgs.size(); i++) {
    sysCline[i] = new char[aArgs[i].size()+1];
    ::strncpy(sysCline[i], aArgs[i].c_str(), aArgs[i].size()+1);
}
sysCline[aArgs.size()] = NULL;

// Construct environment
std::vector<std::string> aEnv; 
aEnv.push_back("GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1");
aEnv.push_back("SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1");
aEnv.push_back("QUERY_STRING=test=querystring");
aEnv.push_back("REDIRECT_STATUS=200");
aEnv.push_back("REQUEST_METHOD=POST");
aEnv.push_back("CONTENT_TYPE=application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
aEnv.push_back("SCRIPT_FILENAME=/test.php");
aEnv.push_back("CONTENT_LENGTH="+ to_string(sData.length()) );
sysEnv = new char*[aEnv.size() + 1];
for (i=0; i<aEnv.size(); i++) {
    sysEnv[i] = new char[aEnv[i].size()+1];
    ::strncpy(sysEnv[i], aEnv[i].c_str(), aEnv[i].size() + 1);
}
sysEnv[aEnv.size()] = NULL;

execve(sysCline[0], sysCline, sysEnv);
```

When run, i got response:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.13
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=2vdp947ghlg0h8st66c9ll3vt6; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Array
(
)
```

It should be same response with `sh test.sh`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a pipe in order to pass the POST data to the script:

```
char *echocmd[] = {"echo", "var_1=val_1&var_2=val_2", NULL};
int pp[2];
int pid, res;

pipe(pp);

if ((pid = fork()) != 0)
{
   dup2(pp[1], 1);
   close(pp[0]);

   res = execvp(echocmd[0], echocmd);
}
else
{
   dup2(pp[0], 0);
   close(pp[1]);

   res = execve(sysCline[0], sysCline, sysEnv);
}

close(pp[1]);
return res;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @yacc, I found a way, this is demo the way i used
http://cpp.sh/4wgu

The idea is: we will fork current process, use 2 pipes: 1 for stdin and 1 for stdout. in parent process, we will use a pipe to write string to stdin of child process, and in child process, we will dum a pipe for output from child's stdout. with this way, we can write to stdin and read stdout of child process from parent process